# No file BLOB, through JSON from ORACLE to SQL Server

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, json, oracle

i am a student and right now I'm doing an internship working with a local library, and in this case i have the following problem:

In the project i´m making, i need to retrieve image data from a temporal table, constructed in ORACLE that receives its data from some triggers in an INFORMIX DB and parse it through a monitor made in JAVA, in a JSON format to a web service published in C# and insert that image in a SQL Server DB.

I looked around and i found that it was possible to parse images through JSON using Base64 encoding and whatnot but when they talk about it they say that you must have the image path file and encode it. as you may have realized by now, i cant use that route because i don't have those images, best case scenario, the triggers are able to feed some BLOB data (by what I've been told). but i have to insert them in the SQL Server DB as Varbinary(MAX).

To summarize:
-->Informix DB has images  
       -->triggers feed an ORACLE Temp_table (images sent probably as BLOB or CLOB at most)
-->monitor made in JAVA must read those BLOBS or CLOBS and send them through JSON
-->Web Service made in C# must receive that JSON, and insert the images in a SQL Server DB (where they need to be visible, without having the physical file to refer to).

the schema i´m using (it has been IMPOSED to me, i didn't had a saying in this) is something similar to this: (it´s really long and tedious code so i´ll try to make it as neat and clean as possible)

This is the part of the java monitor that specifies which fields from the temp_table are feeding what fields in the JSON structure

```
    public static BookRecordList viewBookRecordTable(Connection connection) throws ExceptionToOracleConcurrent
{
    BookRecordList bookRecordList = new BookRecordList();
    BookRecord bookRecord = new BookRecord();

    Statement stmt = null;

    String query = "SELECT operacion,"
                           + "UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(img_logo,32670,1))"
                           + "x_logo,"
                           + "UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(img_logoGris,32760,1))"
                           +  "UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(r_firma,32670,1)),"
                           +  " FROM "
                           + dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_SHCHEMA() + "."+ dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_TABLE_COLA()
                           + " WHERE (some condition)";
    try 
    {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) 
        {
            try
            {
                bookRecord = new BookRecord();
                bookRecord.setOperacion(rs.getInt("operacion"));
                bookRecord.setImg_logo(rs.getString("img_logo"));
                bookRecord.setImg_logoGris(rs.getString("img_logoGris"))
                bookRecord.setR_firma(rs.getString("r_firma"));

                bookRecord.print();
                bookRecordList.getBookRecordList().add(bookRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                logger.error("Some exception " + dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_TABLE_COLA() + ": " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

                //Process next order
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e ) 
    {
        logger.fatal("Some exception " + dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_TABLE_COLA() + ": " + e.toString());
        throw new ExceptionToOracleConcurrent("exception definition " + dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_TABLE_COLA() + ": " + e.toString());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (stmt != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                stmt.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                logger.fatal("another exception " + e.toString());
            } 
        }
    }

    return bookRecordList;
}
```

This is the part of the java monitor that generates the JSON (the empty cases contain another stuff that goes into the JSON but i sorted that out)

```
    private static String GenerateJSON(SomeClass someClass) throws IOException
{
    int operation = someClass.getOperation();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    String jsonText = "";

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 0:

            //obligatory fields
            obj.put("img_logo",someClass.getImg_logo());

            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:

            //Obligatory fields
            obj.put("img_foto",someClass.getC_empleado());
            obj.put("img_firma",someClass.getC_empleado());
            break;
        case 3:
            obj.put("r_firma",someClass.getR_firma());
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    obj.writeJSONString(out);
    jsonText = out.toString();
    String newJson = jsonText.replace("\\/", "/");
    logger.info("JSON a enviar: " + newJson);
    return newJson;

}
```

The web service is made in C#, it´s another case based program, structured accordingly to the operation number received in the JSON, it calls a number of function and, in the end, it comes down to these two:

this part of the WS receive the parameters of the parsed JSON

```
        public int ActualizarFichaLibro( String img_foto, String r_firma)
    {
        try
        {
            //Define query to insert
            Cmd.CommandText = QueryCFA.ActualizarFicha();

            //Define parameters types to insert
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@img_foto", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@r_firma", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);


            //Define parameters values to insert
            Cmd.Parameters["@img_foto"].Value = img_foto;
            Cmd.Parameters["@r_firma"].Value = r_firma;


            int rowCount = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CerrarConexionBd();
            return rowCount;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

and finally that invokes a simple query, in this particular case, to this one:

```
        public string ActualizarFicha()
    {
        Query = "UPDATE dbo.fichaEmpleado SET( CASE WHEN @img_foto = '' THEN NULL ELSE img_foto = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @img_foto, 2) END,"
                + "CASE WHEN @r_firma = '' THEN NULL ELSE img_firma = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @r_firma, 2) END,"
                +"WHERE (some conditions)";
        return Query;
    }
```

my questions are:
is there a way to do this (sending images from one DB to anther) through JSON, specifically with this massive schema this people got going on? if not is there a way to do it?
the querys for reading a BLOB (possible BLOB) and inserting a Varbinary are well implemented?

I´m sorry for the extremely long explanation, I've been working on this for a week and i cant seem to find a proper way to do it (at least not with this schema, but the bosses don't want to change it)

Comment: Can you try to break this question down into discrete parts?  It has both too much detail, and too little.  For instance, in c#, what web service technology are you using?  ASP.NET, WCF, or something else?  What JSON serializer are you using?  The set of people who could review your SQL code and the set of people who could suggest how to do the JSON serialization might be different, so the presence of all the Oracle-specific code might the latter from reading your entire question.

Comment: Again, sorry for posting such a long question. I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 (ASP.NET) and the serializer i think it is json-simple 1.1.1        and you are suggesting that i should post two different questions? the thing is i think my question will be tagged as answered, many people have asked the parsing images just not without the physical file, but if that's your recommendation Ill give it a try and thanks.